# Xamarin - Make rotations with CoreGraphics.CGAffineTransform

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, async-await, core-graphics, core-animation

I want to make a UI Image rotate while content is downloading and I can't seem to make it rotate.

I have this event:

```
public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
{
    NoConnectionView.Hidden = CheckConnectivityStatus();
    Task.Run(async () => await StartSpinningAnimation(true));
}
```

Which then fires this method:

```
protected async Task StartSpinningAnimation(bool IsSpinning) 
{
    do
    {
        UpdateActiveImage.Transform = CoreGraphics.CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation((float)Math.PI / 4);
    }
    while (IsSpinning);
    return;
}
```

The page will eventually change after files are downloaded so I just want it to spin forever. It does animate at all. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using C# and Xamarin.iOS to develop iOS is a letter bit different from the Native language, Whenever you want to invoke some UI element in your background thread(like you need make some UI do an animation), you must use:

```
InvokeOnMainThread(delegate {
    //Do something related UI stuff
});
```

If you add a try catch for it, you will get the exception like that "You are calling a method that can only be invoked in UI thread";

And by the way, you can not just use a do while to make an animation, I write a sample for you, you can take a look:

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    bool needAnimate = true;
    int count = 0;
    UIView animationView = new UIView();

    public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        animationView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect (50, 50, 100, 100);
        animationView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
        this.Add (animationView);

        this.View.AddGestureRecognizer (new UITapGestureRecognizer (() => {
            Task.Run(async () => await StartAnimation());
        }));
    }

    private async Task StartAnimation() 
    {
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("count = " + count++);
            InvokeOnMainThread(delegate {
                UIView.Animate(0.25,delegate {
                    animationView.Transform = CoreGraphics.CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation((float)Math.PI / 4 * (count/4 + 1));
                });
            });
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
        }
        while (needAnimate);
        return;
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }
}
```

The animation is not smoothly, you need to optimize it yourself.

If you still have some questions, just leave here, I will check it latter.

Hope it can help you and welcome to Xamarin.

Comment: Thanks for your lengthy explanation. I'm new to Xamarin and I'm more experienced as a web dev so I am learning a lot about how apps are different. I'll try your code and see how it works.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'm able to rotate my loading circle. What you say about threading and main ui thread makes a lot of sense as well as the UI has it's own thread where memory is allocated and doing await task by itself would break the code.

Comment: Another suggestion you should also take a look about CABasicAnimation.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `UIView.AnimateNotify` to perform the animation with `CoreGraphics` and totally avoid spin-loops to do something like this.

#### Example that spins an image 180 degrees and back repeating forever until stopped:

```
bool _animateStopping = false;
protected void SpinningAnimation(bool animate)
{
    if (_animateStopping) return;
    _animateStopping = !animate;
    if (animate)
    {   
        UIView.AnimateNotify(1,
        () =>
            {
                image.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation((nfloat)(Math.PI)); // in one second, spin 180 degrees
            },
        (bool finished) =>
        {
            UIView.AnimateNotify(1,
            () =>
                {
                    image.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation(0); // in one second, spin it back
                },
            (bool finished2) =>
            {
                SpinningAnimation(true);
            });
        });
     }
    else {
        UIView.AnimateNotify(1,
        () =>
            {
                image.Alpha = 0; // fade away in one second
            },
        (bool finished) =>
        {
            image.RemoveFromSuperview();
            _animateStopping = false;
        }
    );}
}
```

#### Usage:

```
image = new UIImageView(new CGRect(100, 100, 100, 100));
image.Image = UIImage.FromFile("wag.png");
Add(image);
SpinningAnimation(true);
await Task.Delay(5000); // simulate performing downloads, when done stop the animiation
SpinningAnimation(false);
```